# Null value in trigger.new context variable

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a simple trigger that updates lead address filed from another custom object. When I am trying to add lead id in set variable, the following error is thrown:

> argument cannot be null exception

Snippet code:

```
Trigger trigger_name on lead (before insert){
    Set<id> setid = new set<id>();
    For(lead of : trigger.new )
    {
        setid.add(of.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ids are not available in records before insert in trigger yet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide valid code. This code does not compile, so we can't possibly help you.

Answer (score 3):

As @Samir said, the id field is not available in a before insert trigger because Id's are available after insert.

Also, there's a problem with your code. That's not how you instantiate a Set of Id's.

Here's the right code:

```
   Trigger yourTriggerName on lead (after insert){
       Set<Id> leadSet = new Set<Id>();
       for(Lead lead : Trigger.new)
       {
          leadSet.add(lead.id);
       }
   }
```

Comment: missed the set instantiation.My Bad!!

Comment: No problem. There were so many problems in the code...

Answer (score 1):

In before insert trigger,id is not available as the record is not yet inserted,To get the id, change your trigger definition to -

```
Trigger triggerName on lead (after insert)
```

Comment: Valid point, but that would not cause a NullPointerException (NPE).

Comment: error can be because of the trigger name i guess. There should be no space in triggerName

Comment: Still iam getting the same error.....iam trying add text filed in to set(string)where external id is enabled on that filed.....

Comment: Please upload your full trigger